# Rails w/ jQuery AutoComplete - Force AutoComplete entry

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jQuery's AutoComplete with my Rails text fields. Is there a way to force them to select one of the AutoComplete entries (not allow them to submit something that we don't have in our database)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a many-to-many relation I suggest you try the jQuery tokenizedInput plugin.
Ryan did recently a nice screencast on this topic:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields

Answer (score 2):

You could check via jQuery on submit...

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {

    // These are the values returned by AutoComplete
    var matches = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

    // Assuming Array.indexOf(), otherwise extend the prototype
    if (matches.indexOf($('input').val() == -1) {
       event.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

Keep in mind, this only stops a JavaScript enabled user from submitting. A user with it disabled will submit it just fine.

Comment: @Nikita How else would auto complete work if they can't enter text into an input field?